# RoR3 redirects not including RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger, reverse-proxy

On my public-facing Apache2 server access to my Rails 3 app is via a sub-URI, like

```
https://www.myserver.com/myapp/controller...
```

that server is configured for reverse proxy to another Apache2 server hosting the Rails app via Passenger:

```
http://intranet.server.com/myapp
```

In my VirtualHost settings for the intranet server I have

```
SetEnv RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT "/myapp"
```

In my config/environments/production.rb file I uncommented the line

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

This way, the very first executing method in my app issues:

```
logger.debug { "The environment variable RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT is presently #{ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']}" }
```

and sure enough, in the production log file you see:

```
The environment variable RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT is presently /myapp
```

However, the next line in the log is, which is obviously what the browser goes to:

```
Redirected to https://www.myserver.com/controller/action
```

I learned about this environment variable here on Stackoverflow, so that's one person for whom it worked, but one other person chimed it didn't to which another said it did.  So with my experience, we're now at a tie.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my error.  The reverse proxy settings on the external server referenced just the hostname of the internal server and left off the path to my RoR3 app.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, being able to use the ENV var directly was changed quite some time ago:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1946-setting-a-relative-root-url-via-a-web-server-not-possible-anymore

So in environment.rb (or an initializer) you could set config.action_controller.relative_url_root = ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']

Comment: I think that was a 2.1 to 2.2 change.  In 3.0 (at least according to someone's cut&paste of the source elsewhere here, Rails is doing what you suggested already.  That's why in my case the logger message showed that it was set as I was expecting.  Unfortunately something else I must have done is undoing it, or it really isn't working yet.

Comment: I did go over and read the lighthouse ticket.  Just for grins then I added a logger.debug message to report the value.  What you get is the nag message : DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionController::Base.relative_url_root is ineffective. Please stop using it. I'm using Rails 3.0.3

Answer (score 1):

Wow, thanks a lot,
i finally figure it out.

it seems that we need to do proxy to the exact **relative url** on destination rails:,
the same matching uri on apache.

`eg: http://localhost/example/ to http://localhost:3000/example/`

these example below has been tested on Rails 4:

so in proxy httpd.conf:

> ProxyRequests Off
>      ProxyPreserveHost On
>      < Proxy *>
>      Order deny,allow
>      Allow from all
>      < /Proxy>
>
> ProxyPass /**example** http:// localhost:3000/**example**
>
> ProxyPassReverse /**example** http:// localhost:3000/**example**

Then next, in rails config.ru:

> require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  **FILE**)
>      #run Rails.application
>      map ActionController::Base.config.relative_url_root do
>        run **Examplerails**::Application
>      end
>
> map "/" do
>        run Examplerails::Application
>      end

Finally, in config/application.rb

> module Examplerails
>        class Application < Rails::Application
>        config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/**example**"
>        end
>      end

Please note closely on trailing /.
Some have trailing slash while others dont need it.
Also remove some spacing between tag and url in this code above,
im trying to format it to be displayed here.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread on the Rails Github useful: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5122

I ended up doing the following in config/routes (I configured `relative_url_root` via the RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT environment variable):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do |*args|
  scope Rails.application.config.relative_url_root || "/" do
    ...
  end
end
```